# any way to pass a function with 2 input params in java?

Tags: java, lambda, delegates, callable

how can i pass a `Function` like object in java which gets 2 params or more?

I have this code:

```
public String getSrcAfterWait(final By by) {
    String currentSrc;
    try {
        currentSrc = tryToGetSrc(by);

    } catch (StaleElementReferenceException ex)
    {
        currentSrc = tryToGetSrc(by);
    }
    return currentSrc;
}

private String tryToGetSrc(By by) {
    WebElement webElement = getElementAfterWaitForDisplay2(by);
    String currentSrc = null;
    if (webElement != null) {
        currentSrc = webElement.getAttribute("src");
    }
    return currentSrc;
}

private String tryToGetText(final By by) {
    String currentSrc = null;
    WebElement webElement = getElementAfterWaitForDisplay2(by);
    if (webElement != null) {
        currentSrc = webElement.getText();
    }
    return currentSrc;
}

public String getButtonTextAfterWait(final By by) {
    String currentText;
    try {
        currentText = tryToGetText(by);

    } catch (StaleElementReferenceException ex)
    {
        currentText = tryToGetText(by);
    }
    return currentText;
}
```

and I wanted to generalize it like that:

```
public <T,V> V tryGetAttribute(final By by, Function<T,V> getFunc) {
    WebElement webElement = getElementAfterWaitForDisplay2(by);
    V answer = null;
    if (webElement != null) {
        try {
            answer = getFunc.apply(webElement, getFunc);//
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
    return answer;
}

public String getButtonTextAfterWait(final By by) {
    String currentText;
    Function<WebElement, String> getFunc = webElement -> webElement.getText();
    try {
        currentText = tryGetAttribute(by, getFunc);

    } catch (StaleElementReferenceException ex) {
        currentText = tryGetAttribute(by, getFunc);
    }
    return currentText;
}
```

but I don't see any way to pass a function with 2 input params.

Is there a way or it's not efficient to abstract?

Comment: Two comments on code style: You are not abbreviating most of the words you use as method or variable names, but then there is "Src" in between. At least for me, that makes the whole **source** code much harder to read - meaning: you gain nothing from typing "src" instead of "source". Second: getSrcAfterWait() ... if "try" throws an exception, you just call the method again in the catch block - why is that? To be sure that the exception will be thrown again and not be caught then?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. (1) I used Src because this is the actual name of the attribute. `"src"`. No abbreviation, just using the original name. (2) please look at this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29590715/staleelementreferenceexception-even-when-i-use-fluentwait. How would you implement the suggested solution otherwise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least in Java8, there is `BiFunction`

See:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/BiFunction.html

If you need more arguments; what is preventing you from simply creating your own "TripleFunction", and so on?

Another option is to define a new class that combines the two/three/... arguments you have to pass.